# Identities involving covariant derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Is there an identity that says for a tensor of rank $4$, if we cycle the indices, including the index with respect to which its covariant derivative is taken, will the sum of all those quantities yield $0$?

What I mean is, I came across an identity that went like this,

$$A_{ij,k} + A_{jk,i} + A_{kj,i}=0$$

where $A_{ij}= \text{curl} \ B_i$.

My question is when I have a rank-$4$ tensor, say, $C_{ijkl}$, will it satisfy the following identity,

$$C_{ijkl,t} + C_{jklt,i} + C_{klti,j} + C_{ltij,k} + C_{tijk,l}= 0 \ ?$$